# Difference between methods with and without generics

Tags: c#

Can someone help me understand advantages and disadvantages (if any) between the following methods which do the same function of storing away the entity to azure (in my case)?

```
public bool Save<T>(string tableName, T entity) where T : TableEntityBase, new()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

vs

```
public bool Save(string tableName, TableEntityBase entity)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: both cases throw an exception S:

Comment: It might have been a mistake, but the first one allows for `new T()`, whereas the second one is probably an abstract class... hence you cannot do `new TableEntityBase()`.

Comment: I don't see much advantage since your generic variable has been specialized to the same object (say rather than an interface).

Comment: @Dweeberly - you don't put interfaces on models.

Answer (score 0):

With generic method you can pass a parameter T only if

- it is a subclass of `TableEntityBase` and
- have a public parameter-less constructor

Now you can be sure that `new T();` won't throw an exception..

---

but in case of non-generic method

```
new TableEntityBase();
```

could throw an exception incase it doesn't have a parameterless constructor

Comment: "Throw an exception"? The compiler will already complain about the missing constructor and won't let you start the program!